# Webbrowser clicar em botão sem name e ID DELPHI

Tags: html, delphi, navegador-de-internet

Sei que pra mim clicar neste botão aqui!

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit"  name="avancar" value="   Avancar  " onclick="return onSubmit();">
```

Eu utilizo este codigo

```
webBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('avancar', 0).click;
```

mais quando o botão não tem nome o que eu faço neste caso aqui

```
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button-default" onclick="calcula()">Calcular</a></td>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar neste caso ?

Answer (score 1):

tente isso:

```
procedure TForm1.btnFazerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   documento: IHTMLDocument2;
   elemento: IHTMLElement;
   intIndex: Integer;
begin
   documento := wbGeral.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
   for intIndex := 0 to documento.links.length - 1 do
   begin
      elemento := documento.links.item(intIndex, '') as IHTMLElement;
      if elemento.innerText = 'Calcular' then
      begin
         elemento.click;
         Exit;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Importe o ActiveX Microsoft HTML Object Library para ter acesso aos tipos IHTMLElement e IHTMLDocument2