# Webbrowser clicar em botão ou link sem name e ID DELPHI

Tags: html, delphi, navegador-de-internet

Ola galera eu sei que para clicar neste botão aqui

> input type="submit" id="btnSubmit"  name="avancar" value="   Avancar  " onclick="return onSubmit();">

se utilizar este código

> webBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('avancar', 0).click;

mais quando o botão ou link não tem nome nem id, o que eu faço neste caso aqui

> a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button-default" onclick="calcula()">Calcular"

Alguém pode me ajudar neste caso ?

Comment: Já deve ter solução em outra(s) pergunta(s) com título similar, mas você pode buscar o elemento "a" pelo "parent" dele... O parent é o elemento pai, onde o link ou botão está contido.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134673/14539